# Custom post types problem

Tags: custom-post-types, themes, theme-options

I have in my blog around 2k+ posts in 15 categories and around 1k tags. The problem now is that the website I bought the theme from decided to upgrade/update their themes infrastructure and now I need to export my normal posts into a custom post type. Ill explain below.

To be able to use their portofolio grid template they have created a custom post type called portofolio and all posts created with that custom post type will be displayed in a portofolio grid style.

Before the upgrade this was different, once you added a post category you could select the template you wanted to use for that category, but now they decided to create custom post type called "portofolio" and all posts in there will be displayed in the grid portofolio template.

They turned around and said to me that i must start from square one since there is no way to export normal posts into the new custom post type.

So what are my chances guys? The theme is called videogrid by themefuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend pTypeConverter instead of Post Type Switcher. I've run into a couple of odd issues when using it. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ptypeconverter/

Answer (score 1):

Try this plugin: [Post Type Switcher](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-type-switcher/)